# How to deal with spaces in a variable

Tags: shell, shell-script, find, recursive, command-substitution

I'm working on some scripting:

```
for x in `find ./ -name *.pdf`
do
  echo pathname $x
done
```

My filenames are `Test1 ( Volume II)`, `Test2 ( Volume II)`.
I'm getting a return of

```
pathname Test1
pathname (
pathname Volume
pathname II
…
```

How do I get it to stay as one variable?

Comment: See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 10):

As said many time on this site, leaving a variable expansion (as in `$var`) or command substitution (as in `` `cmd` `` or `$(cmd)`) (or arithmetic expansion (as in `$((11 * 11))`) in most shells) unquoted in Bourne/POSIX shells is the split+glob operator.

The content of `$var` or the output of `cmd` (without the trailing newline characters) is split according to the current value of the `$IFS` special variable (which by default contains the SPC, TAB, and NL characters (and NUL in `zsh`)) and each word resulting of that splitting is subject to filename generation also known as *globbing*.

For instance, if `find` ouputs `./foo bar.pdf\n./*foo*\tbar.pdf\n` (`\t` meaning TAB and `\n` NL), with the default value of `$IFS`, the command substitution will expand to `./foo bar.pdf\n./*foo*\tbar.pdf` (trailing newline removed), and then be split into `./foo`, `bar.pdf`, `./*foo*`, and `foo.pdf` and `./*foo*` which is a wildcard pattern will be expanded into as many arguments as there are non-hidden files in the current directory whose name contains `foo`.

If you want to split on newline characters only, you need to set `$IFS` to newline only:

```
IFS='
'
```

If you don't want the wildcard patterns to be expanded, you need to disable it with

```
set -f
```

However note that newline is as valid a character as any in a file name, so more generally, the `find -print` output cannot be post-processed reliably.

An output like:

```
./a.pdf
./b.pdf
```

either means the `a.pdf` and `b.pdf` files in the current directory, or the file called `b.pdf` in the `a.pdf\n.` directory.

Some `find` implementations like GNU `find` (where it originated from) have a `-print0` predicate to output the filename followed by a NUL character instead of a NL character. With standard `find`, you can use `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` with the same result. NUL is the only character that cannot occur in a filename.

However, `zsh` is the only shell that can store a NUL character in its variables (like the `$IFS` character), so:

```
IFS=$'\0'
for i in `find ... -print0`; do
  ...
done
```

(no need for `set -f` in `zsh` since `zsh` doesn't do globbing upon command substitution) will work in `zsh` but not in other shells.

Best, and portably, is to have `find` call the commands you want to run on those files. As @Gnouc suggests:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec the command {} \;
```

If you need anything more complex involving shell statements, you can still do things like:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c '
  for i do
    something complex with "$i"
  done' sh {} +
```

With `zsh` or `bash`, you can also do:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    whatever with "$file"
  done
```

However note that the stdin within the loop is affected.

`zsh` (since 1990) has most of the functionality of `find` included in its globbing capabilities through a syntax where you can specify any level of subdirectories (`(*/)#` syntax or its simpler form `**/`) and globbing qualifiers (which are the pendant of the `-type f`, `-mtime`, `-perm`... in `find`).

The `**/` part of that was copied by `ksh93` in 2003, `fish` in 2005, `bash` in 2009 and `tcsh` in 2010 (though `tcsh` also copied the `***/` part). And all of them do not enable it by default. Unfortunately, note that both `bash` and `fish` `**` do follow symlinks to directories (like `-L`/`-follow` in `find`, or `***` in `zsh` or `tcsh`).

In those shells, you can find `pdf` files in any level of subdirectories without having to rely on `find`, but note that caveat above about `fish` and `bash`, and only `zsh` has the globbing qualifiers.

So, for instance, the `zsh` equivalent of:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -type f -exec ls -ld {} +
```

would be:

```
ls -ld ./**/*.pdf(D.)
```

While with `bash`, you'd have to do something like:

```
shopt -s failglob
shopt -s globstar
files=(./**/*.pdf) &&
  for i do
    [ -f "$i" ] && ! [ -L "$i" ] && set -- "$i" "$@"
    shift
  done && ls -ld "$@"
```

Answer (score 4):

The safest way is to use globbing:

```
for file in *pdf; do echo pathname "$file"; done
```

If you need to find all pdf recursively, do this:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*pdf; do echo pathname "$file"; done
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `bash`'s `**/` follows symlinks when descending the directory tree, which is generally not what you want, you may want to use `ksh93`'s one (which `bash` copied it from and doesn't have the issue) or even better `zsh`'s one (which `ksh93` copied it from) where you can have most of the functionality of `find` through its globbing qualifiers.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in one-liner:

```
find ./ -name "*.pdf" -exec echo pathname {} \;
```

Comment: Do you try my solution? Do you know the meaning of `{}` in `find` command?

Comment: @terdon, the point of Gnouc's is that `find` will take care of the looping (using loops in shell is generally bad practice) and will call any command you want it to run, here `echo` like in the OP's question. Granted, `echo` is a bad choice of commands, but that's the command the OP was using.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I took the question to be asking how to safely store a file name with spaces in a bash variable. I imagine the OP is doing something more complex then `echo pathname $foo`. This solution is identical to what the OP is doing and its output can still not be saved in a variable.

Comment: @Gnouc I get what you mean to do with `-exec` but you still can't use this to save `find`'s output in a variable. Granted if all the OP wants is to print the string `pathname` before the actual path, then this is all you need. But not if the intention is more complex than what `-exec` can handle. And yes, I know what `{}` is :).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options.  Sticking with a looping solution, you can use `read` to read a line at a time into a variable:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" | while IFS= read -r x
do
  echo pathname "$x"
done
```

You can also use `xargs -0` and `find -print0` to handle any sort of special characters:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 echo pathname
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking for a couple hours to find a solution for the default FreeBSD shell (/bin/sh), I finally came up with my own solution. It involves using sed to destroy/create whitespace. This will also allow you to change variables within your loop and use them externally, unlike using  a while loop (while loops spawn subshells in /bin/sh).

```
REMOTE_FOLDER=/media/images
FILE_LIST=$(find $REMOTE_FOLDER | sed 's/ /\/\/\/\//g')
for FILE in $FILE_LIST; do
    FILE=$(echo $FILE | sed 's/\/\/\/\// /g')
    # do whatever you need to do with $FILE
done
```